# Cut out size for 36” range

Tags: carpentry, trim-carpentry

My new home has a 30” cut out for a range. I’m buying a 36” range, What should the width opening be to accommodate for this larger size?

Comment: Width of the stove or by stove instructions.  A free standing oven/stove range I like about an inch or two extra.  Installation instructions override everything.

Comment: Peruse the no-doubt Fantabulous Installation Manual. Or send the range back to whichever import-drop-shipper has no manual and no NRTL listing for the appliance, either.

Comment: Most major manufacturers (GE, Whirlpool, etc.) have very detailed instructions include precise dimensions available either on their own web sites or on major retailers such as Home Depot. As a general rule, they will typically size the appliances just a drop smaller (e.g., 35-7/8") than the nominal dimension, but you really need to check the instructions.

Comment: If you specify the brand/model, someone might be generous enough to look it up for you, but...

Comment: Our profssionally cut soapstone counters have an extra 0,315 inches total (5/16") over the nominal width for the stove. We currently have a slide in range in place and it fits with room to spare. Slide in ranges are designed to work with an exact nominal width. A high end freestanding range might require a little over the exact nominal width. Note that you want to have side gaps as small as possible because free-standing rnages do not normally have an overlapping top like a slide in. One brand of high end free-standing 30" range lists the width as 29.9".

Answer (score 4):

The installation instructions for your new range should specify minimum width required for installation.  Without knowing the specific make/model it's impossible to say, but a safe guess would be a minimum of 36" wide.